# Explaining Preed's behaviour in Titan A.E

Tags: titan-a-e

In the, now rather venerable, animated science fiction movie Titan A.E. there is a scene in which Preed and Gune are left to watch out for Drej as the rest of the crew visit the Gaoul to ask them about Cale's map. They do a bad job of it and slack off while Drej fighters attack the advance party.

> However, later we find out that Preed is working for the Drej, even more intimately than the mercenary Captain Korso. Therefore the alien could be expected to have possibly turned a blind eye in order to increase the Drej chance of securing Cale.

In view of this, is Preed's apparent incompetence real or feigned?

Answer (score 3):

Since he was working for the Drej and he was extremely haughty, a backstabber and only cared for himself so his failure at guard duty was probably due to his narcissism.
The director, Don Bluth, has a site [here](http://donbluth.wikia.com/wiki/Titan_A.E.)